# PHP increment integer onClick

Tags: php, html

I've already searched for different ways to do this but no luck with fixing my problem.
My code looks basically like this:

```
<?php
   $attnum = 1;
?>

<button type="button" onClick="<?php $attnum++ ?>">+</button>
<h3><em>att<?php echo "$attnum" ?>: </em></h3>
```

When the page loads it have already added 1 on $attnum. I only want to add on $attnum when the button is pressed. What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use PHP on client-side. You are supposed to do this with Javascript.

Comment: Do you want the server (PHP code) to know about this change to `$attnum` or do you just want to start the javascript processing off at a specific number?

Comment: @Firat-Akandere How would you do so?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Only client side. My goal with this function is, when I press the button it will add one more "attX" below the previous and increment the X with one everytime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it server side, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // Page was not reloaded via a button press
   if (!isset($_POST['add'])) {
       $_SESSION['attnum'] = 1; // Reset counter
   }
?>

<form method='post'>
<input name='add' type="submit" value='+'>
<h3><em>att<?php echo $_SESSION['attnum']++ ?>: </em></h3>
</form>
```

If you want to do it client side, do it like this:

```
<button id='add' type="button">+</button>
<h3><em>att<span id='val'>1</span>: </em></h3>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('val').innerHTML++;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The client side works like a charm!

Comment: Is it possible to check the value of the "span" so I can disable subtraction if the value is 1?

Comment: `document.getElementById('val').innerHTML` is the value of the `span` tag. If you're subtracting numbers, you'd just change the initial value and add an if statement around the code that decrements the value.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up HTML (client side) and PHP (server side).
If you want to increment a server variable in PHP whenever a user clicks the button, you have to notify the server, for instance using ajax call.

Comment: Oh, can I use javascript? I want to keep everything client side.

Comment: if you want to keep everything in the client side, consider removing PHP. For instance:
`<script>
   var attnum = 1;
</script>

<button type="button" onClick="attnum++">+</button>
<h3><em>att<?php echo "$attnum" ?>: </em></h3>`

Comment: Cheers, I will give it a try!

Comment: Just use document.write javascript function

Comment: Mathew, could you update your code so I can use document.write, please? I'm not good with javascript.

Comment: Sure
`<script> var attnum = 1; </script> <button type="button" onClick="attnum++">+</button><h3><em>att<script>document.write(attnum)</script>: </em></h3>`

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this by using Javascript, check this fiddle:

HTML:

```
<button id="button" type="button">+</button>
<h3><em>att<span id="att">1</span>:</em></h3>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var attnum = 1;
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('att').innerHTML = ++attnum;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a79bb31b/9/

Comment: With this code, nothing happens. If I use your fiddle code it just opens an alert window with number 1.

Comment: It's still with alert.

Comment: Are you sure you are not checking the first revision? Check the revision number 9.

Comment: I click the link you've submitted. Try creating a new link.

Answer (score 1):

create a function using javascript instead and call it in the onClick attribute of the button.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onClick='add()'>+</button>
<h3><em>att <span id='att-num'></span> : </em></h3>
```

add script tag somewhere (I put it in the bottom part usually):

```
<script>
  function add() {
    document.getElementById('att-num').innerHTML++;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Like this

```
<button type="button" onClick="funct('<?php $attnum++ ?>')">+</button>
<h3><em>att<?php echo "$attnum" ?>: </em></h3>
```

and create a new javascript function